# Omniauth and LinkedIn: Step 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Can anyone help with LinkedIn's instructions for setting up omniauth.

I'm really struggling to understand how to set it up in my Rails 4, Devise, Omniauth app.

I'm currently getting this error: Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key.

The LinkedIn Developer instructions suggest this is an error with Step 1. I have registered my app.https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

I don't understand how to do step 3. Where do I put the redirect code? How does it work with the rails config. Please can someone help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically the step 3 it's saying that you can ask for different permissions in each request by the url, but for your gem you should not worry about this, just skip to the configuration(step 4) of your app in linkedin([settings](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer)) and select witch permission to use with all users, this will trigger ask the same for all the user of your page.

Now if you really want to have different behaviors for each user, lets say some users will just login and other will manage their linkedin profile thought your page, you should change the behavior of the workflow of omniauth, facebook-omniauth-gem have an option called setup that you can pass into config.omaniauth in devise initializer, this will trigger an extra step to change the url and there you can put that options, i imagine that linkedin should have something similar.

I just do an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107206/1802527) for facebook, but i explained for general use, look at that if you have troubles, regards!

Comment: Hi Alexis. I'm struggling. I have omniauth.rb initialiser ([] are replaced with codes:  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :linkedin, "[key]", "[secret]",
     REDIRECT_URI = [http:// to homepage] #Redirect users
     STATE = [long code] #A unique long string that is not easy to guess
     :scope => "r_basicprofile r_emailaddress", 
     :field => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name" ],
     :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}} 
 end

Comment: Since you are using devise, use omniauth from devise, remove omniauth.rb and add in devise.rb config.omniauth :linkedin, secret_key, secret(not remember exactly the names now, i'm writting from my cel) with that devise will configure the provider information, let me know if that works, in like 5 hrs i will have my laptop with me for give you a little more help

Comment: config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_ID'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'], you can use your secrets directly in here if you have troubles with setting environment variables, but still is a good practice doing it like that, search for railscast tutorials on omniauth, there you will have a good start, they are a little outdated, but still after see the 4 or 5 videos(not remember exactly how many they where, there are omniauth, omniauth revised, omniauth with devise, facebook and twitter) you start to understand , all omniauths works pretty much the same for simple login, specially with devise.